# Return to the app after successful payment with Flutter and Stripe

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, firebase-dynamic-links, klarna

I'm building an app where the user can purchase an item. The payment is handled by Stripe and Klarna on a website opened with `url_launcher`.

My question is how to properly return the user to the app after the purchase is successful. Stripe allows a `return_url` to be passed which could be a Firebase dynamic link that opens the app. Would this work since the website could possibly have been launched in a in-app browser? Or is it just better to use a `WebView` and monitor the url for the success one?

Any other thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this using [Deep Links.](https://medium.com/flutter-community/deep-links-and-flutter-applications-how-to-handle-them-properly-8c9865af9283)